# External hard drive doesn't show on Mac Finder

Tags: macos, terminal, finder, hard-drive, mount

My external hard drive is not showing in Finder. It shows on Disk Utility but greyed and can not mount from there. I don't want to lose anything from my hard drive.

I have tried force mounting from Terminal. So, I have followed these commands:

```
diskutil list
mount /dev/disk2
ls -la /Volumes/
sudo mkdir /Volumes/usb
sudo mount -t hfs /dev/disk2 /Volumes/usb/
```

But it shows :

```
mount_hfs: error on mount(): error = -1.
mount_hfs: Resource busy
mount: /Volumes/usb failed with 1
```

So, what can I do now to make it visible on Finder without losing any data?

I am using macOS Catalina 10.15.7.

Comment: Did you try the `diskutil  mountDisk` command?

Comment: First try `diskutil info <your_disk_id>`

Comment: There *may* be a soft error on the drive. If it is HFS+ formatted a 3rd party Disk repair tool might do the trick (DiskWarrior is my go-to, but there are others). If it is a hardware issue (failed USB enclosure, drive controller and such) it may require a visit to a computer tech or a visit to a data recovery specialist.